# How to sell a complete product package, without the customer can select just one

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, quantity, package

I need sell product package, but I need that client won't be able to select just one, the default method is like this image below:

[image: Default method]

I need only show to client what products are available on package like this image:

[image: I need this]

But the client cannot be able to change or select products, if the client change the amount, the price just multiply all products on package x2, example:

Total amount of product are 211, if the client change the amount to 2 the total go to 422 and so on...

Obs: I need to sell package of different amounts, like 2 Products on package, 3 or 4 products...

Comment: create a bundle product or create a custom option

Comment: @edit I do this, and what you see on image are Bundle of "Muti Select", but I need that the cliente cannot be able to change one or other product, all product need to to sold togheter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on right track just go for it

- Create a bundle product as you want
- Create bundle option with Input Type radio and assign first product only
- Choose Is required as yes and default for that product
- Create another bundle option like same above step for second product

This will give you 2 option only with required and default in frontend, so user can not choose/update any option.

**Note:** It will display 2 group title in frontend that you have to manage from css.